# Why does the configuration class form a cyclical dependency with itself?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, javabeans

I don't understand what is it about this class that it yields a cyclical dependency injection with itself.
I've tried adding @Lazy annotations or removing the @Autowired from the constructor but it didn't help. Probably there is an elephant in the room that I'm not seeing.

This is what the console displays:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  securityConfiguration defined in file [E:\Users\Adelin\eclipse-workspace2\AuthenticationSpringJWTAngular\target\classes\src\main\configuration\SecurityConfiguration.class]
```

This is the configuration class:

```
package src.main.configuration;

import static org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS;
import static src.main.constant.SecurityConstant.PUBLIC_URLS;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import src.main.filter.JWTAccessDeniedHandler;
import src.main.filter.JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import src.main.filter.JWTAuthorizationFilter;
import src.main.service.IUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private JWTAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter;
    private JWTAccessDeniedHandler jwtAccessDeniedHandler;
    private JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private IUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(JWTAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter,
            JWTAccessDeniedHandler jwtAccessDeniedHandler, JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint,
            IUserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.jwtAuthorizationFilter = jwtAuthorizationFilter;
        this.jwtAccessDeniedHandler = jwtAccessDeniedHandler;
        this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint = jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder amb) throws Exception {
        amb.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()//
                .cors().and() //
                // we're not using sessions, not keeping track of currently logging in users
                // users prove by using a token -> stateless
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS).and() //
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll() // no authentication
                                                                            // needed
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and() // anything else - reqs. authentication
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(jwtAccessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

---

Comment: why you need to receive `BCryptPasswordEncoder` as a field in your configuration class? you could just do `amb.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(this.bCryptPasswordEncoder());` (call the method `bCryptPasswordEncoder()` instead of passing the field) - and, of course, remove the field bCryptPasswordEncoder from the class

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because of this

The constructor of `SecurityConfiguration` is marked `@Autowired` with a parameter of type `BCryptPasswordEncoder` so basically in order to instantiate `SecurityConfiguration` it needs a bean of type `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

But then again, the same class has an instance method which is creating the very bean of type `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

So basically, the constructor cannot be called because it depends on the value returned by the method and the method cannot be called because the constructor has not been called yet to instantiate it.

If you change the method to below (I'm not suggesting it as a solution but just to validate my understanding), then it probably might work.

```
@Bean
public static BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```